# Javascript - function constructor with new keyword

Tags: javascript, constructor

When the below `foo` function is called with `new`, it turns into a constructor function returning the object which gets assigned to `baz`.

```
function foo() {
  this.baz = "baz";
  console.log(`${this.bar} ${baz}`); 
}

var bar = "bar";
var baz = new foo(); // prints undefined undefined
```

The question is why `baz` inside the console statement gets `undefined` value - would it be right to say that while `baz` got hoisted, when new foo() is called, till the function returns the `baz` is not assigned the returned object ?

`console.log(baz)` in a later line prints the returned object correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `baz` doesn't exist in the moment of executing the constructor. `baz` is created after the constructor is executed.

It would work similarly if you used an IIFE:

```
var test = (function() {
  console.log(test) // undefined
  return 'test'
}())
console.log(test) // 'test'
```

Answer (score 2):

In the function there is no `bar` in the `this`. You need to remove the `this` part of the `this.bar`. For `baz` you must use the `this.baz`, because it is attached to the object instance.

```js
function foo() {
  this.baz = "baz";
  console.log(`${bar} ${this.baz}`); 
}

var bar = "bar";
var baz = new foo();
```

This code means

```
this.baz = "baz";
console.log(`${this.bar} ${baz}`);
```

that when you create an object it will have only 
`baz` in it. In the body if you want to access the object's property you need to access via `this`. `${baz}` is undefined because there is no `baz` variable(it will not look in the `this`).So if you need to access the `baz` in the function you need to use `this.baz`.

what about `${this.bar}`, there is no `bar` property in the `this`, only `baz`.

Comment: your answer assumes , the code need to be fixed. not looking for a fix , but confirmation on the explanation for the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) will help you to understand what `this` means.

> Used inside a function, this refers to the current object. What that
>   actually means is specified by the way in which you called that
>   function. If you called it using dot notation or bracket notation on
>   an object, that object becomes this. If dot notation wasn't used for
>   the call, this refers to the global object.

So you are calling `this.bar` inside of `function foo()`. You will get `undefined` because function foo() doesn't have `bar` property.

Also, when you call just `bar` inside of `function foo ()`, It will starts to find bar property.
First inside of `function foo ()` and search it if `global` has bar property.